# How to draw transperent composite with border on image inside canvas in SWT java

Tags: java, swt

I am creating one project in which user can select ROI from image with mouse drag event and selected ROI should be movable and resizable.
This is similar like windows paint does when we open image in paint.
How to make composite(like swt button, text) transparent on image (which is inside canvas).

I have created one canvas and added image in that. I can select ROI from mouse with the help of listener added to canvas(SWT.paint). Here I am taking bounds value and creating one composite to MOVE ROI. I am able to create composite on image, also I am able to move this ROI. But I am unable to make this created ROI transparent.

I am expecting the way windows paint works, same way my project should give me facility to select rectangle on image and move it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to set draw/fill color with alpha value.

In the below example 100 is the alpha value which set the transparency. 255 means no transparency.

Color color = new Color(255, 0, 0, 100);